# egg file needs permission in scrapyd while deploying

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

If I do this for another project means it shows.

```
$ scrapy deploy scrapyd
Packing version 1412325181
Deploying to project "project2" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'eggs'"}
```